# Filter by time range in list of DateTime objects

Tags: c#, datetime, time

I have a list of DateTime objects.

I need to take from this list only those objects that have time part of the date between '00:00:01' and '12:00:00'.

How can I query this list?

If I would make a SQL Query I would do something this way

```
SELECT TspCreated,
    CASE 
        WHEN cast(TspCreated as time) > '00:00:00' AND 
             cast(TspCreated as time) <= '12:00:00' 
             THEN '00 - 12'
        WHEN cast(TspCreated as time) > '12:00:00' AND 
             cast(TspCreated as time) <= '18:00:00' 
             THEN '12 - 18'
        WHEN cast(TspCreated as time) > '18:00:00' AND 
             cast(TspCreated as time) <= '23:59:59' 
             THEN '18 - 24'
    END AS TimeFrame
FROM MyTable
```

EDIT:

Thanks to [Jon Skeet answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27071839/filter-by-time-range-in-list-of-datetime-objects/27071954#27071954) I had the way to use Timespan objects as the boundaries for my query. Unfortunately, in my case that answer is not applicable because Linq-to-Entities does not support usage of `TimeOfDay` property. I have ended up with usage of [Entity Framework Canonical Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738563%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
TimeSpan ts_0 = new TimeSpan( 0, 0, 0 );
TimeSpan ts_12 = new TimeSpan( 12, 0, 0 );
int NumOfIssues = ctx.MyEntitySet.Where( x => 
                      DbFunctions.CreateTime( x.TspUsed.Hour, x.TspUsed.Minute, x.TspUsed.Second ) >= ts_0 &&
                      DbFunctions.CreateTime( x.TspUsed.Hour, x.TspUsed.Minute, x.TspUsed.Second ) < ts_12).Count();
```

Comment: Could you please show us some code of what you have tried so far?

Comment: There are two parts to this: 1) working how to tell whether or not the condition is met for a single element; 2) filtering the list using 1. Which of those are you stuck on? If you haven't looked at LINQ yet, now would be a great time to do so :)

Comment: @ JohnOdom and @ Jon Skeet: I am stuck on the first part. Did'nt started any code still. I dont know where to start with. Why the undervote?

Comment: @JonSkeet: I do know LINQ. The problem is on writing the condition

Comment: Okay, so you can get rid of that part of the question - you're only interested in *one* item... you know what to do with the rest. Now, have you had a look at the properties of `DateTime`? In particular, the `TimeOfDay` property is relevant. Note that the conditions in your SQL are a bit odd... it's more normal to make the lower bound inclusive and the upper bound exclusive.

Comment: @JonSkeet: you're right about the conditions in SQL. I wrote them without thinking. Regarding the TimeOfDay property, that is a TimeSpan, Do I need to check it like `ts1 <= DateTime.TimeOfDay <= ts2` where ts1 and ts2 are the boundaries?

Comment: @Lorenzo: Well not quite... if you want to check two boundaries in one `if` condition, you'd use `if (ts1 <= dateTime.TimeOfDay && dateTime.TimeOfDay < ts2)`. You can't express both inequality checks in a single operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that all you need is the [`DateTime.TimeOfDay`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.timeofday) property. I would then recommend changing your conditions slightly if you're able to, so that the lower bound is *inclusive* and the upper bound is *exclusive*, e.g.

```
var time = dateTime.TimeOfDay;
if (time.Hours < 12)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Morning");
}
else if (time.Hours < 18)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Afternoon");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Evening");
}
```

As an example of why that's handy, your current classification excludes midnight entirely along with anything between 11:59:59pm and midnight, e.g. 11:59:59.999.

Or you could create appropriate `TimeSpan` values for the boundaries and use the regular `<`, `<=` etc operators. For example:

```
TimeSpan noon = new TimeSpan(12, 0, 0);
TimeSpan sixPm = new TimeSpan(18, 0, 0);
TimeSpan time = dateTime.TimeOfDay;
if (time < noon)
{
    ...
}
else if (time < sixPm)
{
    ...
}
else
{
    ...
}
```

Note that with both approaches, I'm only checking one condition per `if` statement, because I basically move through the day, from midnight onwards. If you just wanted to check one band in the middle, you could say:

```
if (noon <= time && time < sixPm)
```

As a slight aside, I've never liked that `TimeOfDay` returns a `TimeSpan` - an elapsed period of time isn't the same as a time of day. If you feel the same and you're doing any significant amount of date/time work, you might want to consider looking at my [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) project, which has a *lot* more types to represent various aspects of dates and times.

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much. I did'nt realized that I could use timespans as boundaries. Thank you.

Comment: Well. Unfortunately this solutions is not available in Linq-To-Entities and I can't use it in my code.

Comment: @Lorenzo: That's why context is so important - you talked about having a *list* of `DateTime` values. You didn't mention Entity Framework at all - if you'd done so, I'd have given a different answer...

Comment: (In other words, I answered the question you *asked* - it's just that the question didn't describe the problem you were really trying to solve.)